# file upload method in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i don't know why file is not uploaded in database.
i am tried to check this method why file is  not uploaded.
this method is used a lots of time. and worked successfully at every time.
if any mistake please correct it.

```
<?php
//database connection successfully worked.
  $manu = $_POST['manu'];    
if(isset($_POST['img_submit']))
{if($_FILES['file']['name']<>"")
    {$file =time().'_'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        if (!copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"file/".$manu))
        {$message = "Invalid File type.Upload only JPEG and GIF files";}            
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $manu)) {$msg2 = "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded";} 
            else{$msg3 = "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";} }
    echo $query = "insert into upload_image (upload_img) values('".$manu."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

}?>    

<form name="form" action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="5">
  <tr><td align="center" colspan="2">&nbsp;<b>Upload Image</b></td></tr>
   <tr>
    <th width="50%">&nbsp;Image Url :</th>
    <td width="50%">&nbsp;<input type="file" name="manu" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="img_submit" value="Upload Image" /></td></tr></table></form>
```

Comment: i know this is duplicate question in stackoverflow.com. but please try to find out why file is not stored in database

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You so don't want to have this code on your server.

```
<?php
    //database connection successfully worked.
    $manu = $_POST['manu'];    
    ...
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $manu)
```

This basically means that if I have control of *my* browser (I have), I can send along a file with a fake MIME type and a full path of my choice in `$_POST['manu']`, and your server will save this file in *any folder I want* where it has write access to, without checking.

Just suppose I were to upload `evil_haxxor_skr1pt.php` with a MIME type of `image/jpeg` somewhere where your server code might find it, *and execute it on my behalf*...

Answer (score 2):

Fr starters, you use the copy() function and move_uploaded_file(). Don't use the copy()! That's a big security breach!

If you want to save in the DB you need to use something like the [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get all the contents of the file, then you just use that data directly into the DB like you did with the `$manu` variable.
Don't forget to filter the input.
By the way, don't use the mysql_* functions, use mysqli_* functions. mysql_* are already too old and outdated.